# grep with pattern of seperate keywords for the same line

Tags: grep

I would like to search from the output of ps command by using grep. The criteria is: it contains the specific username and command.

For instance, with the following ps result:

```
suh1     48980  0.0  0.0 144396 20372 ?        Ss   Mar16   0:20 SCREEN -DR l2
tprossi  52257  0.0  0.0 127344  3264 ?        Ss   Mar13   0:26 SCREEN
mannerh1 54331  0.0  0.0 125368  1288 ?        Ss   14:32   0:00 SCREEN
thakorv1 54791  0.0  0.0 126096  2116 ?        Ss   Mar16   0:00 SCREEN
valiman2 58699  0.0  0.0 125364  1244 ?        Ss   Mar17   0:00 SCREEN
rxue     60121  4.0  0.0 108344  1120 pts/176  R+   14:39   0:00 ps aux
rxue     60122  0.0  0.0 103252   920 pts/176  S+   14:39   0:00 grep -e rxue -e SCREEN
```

I would like to get the process list with user "tprossi" and with command SCREEN.
One solution is:

```
ps aux | grep tprossi | grep -i screen
```

But here the grep is called twice, which is not so elegant. Is there any shortcut? 
I tried also:

```
ps aux | grep -i "tprossi*screen"
```

but it doesn't work :<

Anyone can give some suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You miss a `.`

```
ps aux | grep -i "tprossi.*screen"
```

Without it, you just say repeat `i` zero or more times.
The `.` represent any character.

---

You can also use `awk`

```
ps aux | awk '/tprossi/ && /screen/'  # in any order
```

or

```
ps aux | awk '/tprossi.*screen/'  # in this order
```